# Computing quotients of group by elements of its lower exponent$-p$ central series

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, gap, computational-algebra

Let $G$ be a finite $p−$group of number of generators $d$ and exponent$−p$ class $c$, that is $c$ is the smallest integer satisfying $P_c(G)=1$ in the series
$$
G=P_0(G)≥...≥P_{i−1}(G)≥P_i(G)≥...
$$
Where $P_i(G)=[P_{i−1}(G),G]P_{i−1}(G)^p$.

1/ Can you show me how to calculate $G/P_i(G)$´s using GAP system?

2/ Can you show me how to compute $G/P_1(G)$ using abelianisation and row-echelonisation (by hand)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

The series is in general called the $p$-central series, so the GAP command is `PCentralSeries`.

As for calculating it by hand, you might want to look at section 9.4.2 of Holt/Eick/O'Brien: Handbook of Computational Group Theory.

Comment: Many thanks professor, I hope I can ask you for explanations if I find some ambiguity following the process you guided me to. In fact I start reading your "Notes on Computational Group Theory" it is also very helpful, thanks again